# Exchange 2013 Banner

Tags: smtp, exchange-2013, banner

We have an exchange 2013 server that is failing a reverse SMTP Banner Check:
220 [Internal IP] ESMTP Smtpd;

I have gone into our exchange receive connector for the internet, "Default frontend servername" and have changed the banner to "220 SMTP OK domain" however running the check or connecting through telnet will only give the original, default banner. I decided to change all of the receive connectors (just in case) but I still only get the default banner. I opened up the protocol smtp receive logs and I see:

date, receive connector, seq ect, 220 SMTP OK domain,

I think I am misunderstanding, but how do I change what is displayed and comply with the reverse banner check?

Answer (score 0):

It is Receive Connector setting.
You can change banner [using powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125140%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx), example:

```
Set-ReceiveConnector -Identity <connector name> -Banner <banner> -ConnectionTimeout <timeout>
```

To view Receive Connectors list from your frontend server [use powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998618%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx):

```
Get-ReceiveConnector -Server <server name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the Receive Connector banner. It has zero effect on your ability to send or receive email from the internet and is just a way to pass a poorly designed test.

Changing the receive connector banners can affect your ability to send email internally though, which includes sending email between servers and within users.

I wrote about these poorly designed tests over six years ago. 
http://blog.sembee.co.uk/post/Exchange-2007-and-SMTP-Banner-Tests

The only test that matters is outbound SMTP banner testing, which you have to use another tool. I have written about that here: 
http://blog.sembee.co.uk/post/Exchange-200720102013-Outbound-SMTP-Banner-Testing